# How to list google calendar reminders (not notifications, etc)

Tags: c#, google-calendar-api

I've been trying to list and edits reminders I can add and view in normal web page of Google Calendar, but to no avail.

An example of Google Calendar page where I can see these reminders:
[reminders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv2md.png)

This is a sample code I've used to test listing events:

```
EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(calendarID);
request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
request.TimeMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10);
request.ShowDeleted = false;
request.ShowHiddenInvitations = true;
request.SingleEvents = false;
request.MaxResults = 10;

Events events = request.Execute();
foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{eventItem.Summary}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Access event reminders:

If you want to view the reminders for a certain event, you have to access the property `reminders` from the event. Check information of this property in the [event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events).

In the code you shared, you are only accessing the `Summary` property (the title of the event), so it's not strange that you're not getting information on the reminders. Also, each reminder contains two properties, `useDefault` and `overrides`.

In the library I assume you're using, you have to access [RemindersData](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event.RemindersData.html) for each event, as specified [here](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event.html#Google_Apis_Calendar_v3_Data_Event_Reminders), and access the properties `Overrides` or `UseDefault` from the reminder.

#### Edit event reminders:

If you want to edit these reminders for an event, you would have to call [Events: patch](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.Data.Event.html#Google_Apis_Calendar_v3_Data_Event_Reminders), which updates the fields you specify, while keeping the existing values of the fields you don't specify. Check the corresponding method in the library [here](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/latest/api/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3.EventsResource.PatchRequest.html).

As you can see in the provided reference, you have to provide the fields you want to update in the body (the `RemindersData`), as well as the `calendarId` and the `eventId`.

#### Reference:

- [Calendar API: Reminders and Notifications](https://developers.google.com/calendar/concepts/reminders)
- [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)
- [Events: patch](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch)